# Activate spare for RAID-5 in Disk Utility

Tags: raid, disk, disk-utility, raid5

I have a RAID-5. I'm trying to replace a failing drive in Disk Utility GUI. I added a new drive as a spare, then did "Remove Component" for the failing drive. How do I tell it to actually use the spare (write all the parity data, etc)?

I tried re-adding, because I got nervous...

`$ sudo mdadm /dev/md127 --re-add /dev/sdd`

`mdadm: --re-add for /dev/sdd to /dev/md127 is not possible`

Answer (score 1):

It will automatically use the spare as soon as the array becomes degraded, which either happened before you added the spare, or when you failed and removed the bad drive.  Check the status with `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md127` and it should show that either it is in the process of rebuilding, or it has finished and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md127 --remove /dev/sdd
```

then re-add:

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --add /dev/sdd
```